# Json com C# com nó numerado

Tags: c#, json

Alguém sabe como faço para ler os objetos com esse modelo de arquivos? Parece que o criador não usou `[]` para `Arrays` e também o segundo nó é numerado (não é **chave : valor** como o `json` básico).

```
{  
    "1":{  
        "id":1,
        "nome":"Rodrigo",
        "Apelido":"RK",
        "Fotos":{  
            "120x120":"nome",
            "60x60":"nome",
            "30x30":"nome"
        }
    },
    "2":{  
        "id":1,
        "nome":"Renato",
        "Apelido":"RT",
        "Fotos":{  
            "120x120":"nome",
            "60x60":"nome",
            "30x30":"nome"
        }
    },
    "3":{  
        "id":1,
        "nome":"Luis",
        "Apelido":"LP",
        "Fotos":{  
            "120x120":"nome",
            "60x60":"nome",
            "30x30":"nome"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu aconselharia a criação de duas classes

```
public class Items: Dictionary<string, Item>
{

}

public class Item
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("nome")]
    public string  Nome { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("Apelido")]
    public string Apelido { get; set; }    
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("Fotos")]        
    public Dictionary<string, string> Fotos { get; set; }
}
```

e com um simples comando utilizando a biblioteca [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/), faça o exemplo abaixo:

```
string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("./base.json");

Items objectJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Items>(json);
```

essa variável `objectJson` agora é um tipo da classe `Items` é só acessar as chaves e valor facilmente para buscar as informações contidas no arquivo `json`.

Comment: OK! Deu certo! Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Se for a solução pode aceita-la como resposta? @RodrigoKönig

Comment: Claro! Como faço isso? Sou novo aqui!

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade no `json` é sempre a combinação `chave:valor`

Note que o nó que você diz ser numerado é uma string: `"1":{`

Logo a forma de acesso é o padrão:

```
string id = Convert.ToString(jsonObj["1"]["id"]);
string nome = Convert.ToString(jsonObj["1"]["nome"]);
```

Comment: Mas eu teria que fazer um loop para ler o 2º nó? Pois ele tem números aleatórios. De 1 a 5000. Não dá pra recuperar manualmente.